# understanding Dojo closure example

Tags: javascript, dojo, closures

In the Dojo docs there is an example:

```
require([
"dojo/query",
"dojo/_base/array",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/domReady!"
], function(query, array, domConst){
function topLinks(){
    var headings = query('h2,h3');

    array.forEach(headings, function(elm){
        var topLink = domConst.create("a", {
            href: "#top",
            innerHTML: "^top"
        });

        domConst.place(topLink, elm, "before");
    });
}
});
```

I assume that function(elm) is a closure with 'elm' being an abbreviation for element, and in this case 2 closures are created, with elm = h2 for the first closure, and elm = h3 for the second closure.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like CSS, `dojo/query` supports grouped selectors.  `h2,h3` will match all `h2` and `h3` elements, and `headings` will be a `dojo/NodeList` with all `h2` and `h3` elements found in the document.  `array.forEach` simply iterates through the entire `NodeList` in order, so each time through the function `elm` references the next `h2` or `h3` element.

Comment: Okay, right there can be lots of h2, h3s in the DOM.  But isn't h2, h3 two selectors not one?

Comment: Yes, technically they are considered grouped selectors, so maybe I didn't pick the best words there.